# Safari browser in Ipad renders only the first page of pdf - Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, embed

The following code has been used to render the pdf in browser. It works fine in `chrome` browser but it doesn't work in `Safari` browser in ipad. It just renders the first page of pdf. Another observation is the first page is converted into image (as per the console)

```
<embed src={props.filePath} height="900" width="100%" type='application/pdf'/>
```

Comment: may be this will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480804/problems-displaying-pdf-in-iframe-on-mobile-safari