# pdf in iframe only first page on iphone/ipad

Tags: html, css, pdf, iframe

I am trying to display the content of a pdf with an `iframe`. Everything is working fine on a normal computer. However on mobile devices of apple (IPhone/IPad) only the first page of the pdf is getting displayed.

Here is my code where I already added some scrolling styles because I thought it was a problem related to the scrolling, but If I make the `iframe` very small it is possible to scroll! However the problem is still the same...only the first page is visible.

```html
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <iframe height="260" width="280" src="info.pdf"> </iframe> 
</div>
```

```css
.scroll-wrapper {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: and printing is broken too. 
if you debug the page, you will notice the pdf 
is not embeded as pdf, but as image. 

apparently this is broken since ios8

Comment: For me below things worked may be it will work for you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480804/problems-displaying-pdf-in-iframe-on-mobile-safari

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using viewport.
Or using responsive breakpoints

```
@media screen and (max-width:512px) {
   size:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width:512px) {
    .scroll-wrapper{
        overflow-y:scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
        width: 400px;enter code here
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
iframe {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.