# pdf in iframe only first page on iphone/ipad view

Tags: html, pdf, safari

I have added embedded pdf but only first page is displayed in chrome and safari mobile. I need your help.

< iframe src="soz.pdf"
frameborder="0" id="myiframe" style="height:100%; width:100%;">

---this is my code

Comment: Alp Selvi, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think much is likely to have changed for the past few years so

[Adobe response](https://blogs.connectusers.com/connectsupport/unable-to-open-full-pdf-on-ios-browsers/) is

> PDFs are not supported in the mobile browsers if embedded inside an HTML page. only first page would be displayed. Safari (and UIWebViews) supports the rendering of PDFs if given the absolute URL.

> Solution:
> **This issue a limitation mobile browsers** [sic] if PDF files are embedded inside an HTML page.

Workaround:

These links can be opened by **appending** ***/default/connect.pdf***
For Example try these 2 links to see firstly
https://my.adobeconnect.com/px0fs4dlnp3o/ **can be loaded fully by using**   https://my.adobeconnect.com/px0fs4dlnp3o/default/connect.pdf

other older suggestions here
[Problems displaying PDF in iFrame on Mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480804/problems-displaying-pdf-in-iframe-on-mobile-safari)

Most common answer from others is, hand your precious data to google analytics, ensure you use `?embedded=true&url=`

https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf

Comment: These solutions have many limitations, you need your PDF to available externally for google to load it so this is not suitable for any sensitive information

Answer (score 1):

I found a work a workaround for that, we can use the following link:

`http://docs.google.com/gview?url=${url}&embedded=true`,
for example:

```
< iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://link_to_file.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="0" id="myiframe" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ColdFusion you can detect it's an iPhone, then use a cflocation tag to push the user to the PDF.

```
<cfif findNoCase('iPhone', cgi.http_user_agent,1)>
<!--- relocate to iphone version of the mobile site --->
    <cflocation url="https://yourWebSite.org/pdf/the_pdf.pdf" addToken="no">
</cfif>
```

I assume you could do something similar with PHP using the Header Location tag. Also using JavaScript you could detect the iPhone and push the user to the PDF.